# Full words for some "key words"/"abbreviation" in swift

Tags: swift

I've been writing code in swift for more than a year, but still I can't understand, why does someone called "key words"/"abbreviation" so. I'm not native, so. It's sometimes difficult to guess. Hope someone know =)

- var - variable
- let - ???(constant?)

Is "let" separate word? Can you give few examples of usage if it is so?

Is it close to: "Let it as it is!"?

In protocol **Comparable**, I've found such method:

```
public static func <=(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

- lhs - left ??? (probably argument???)
- lrs - left ??? (probably argument???)

Comment: In the scope of a class/struct and so on, we generally refer to immutable (`let`) and mutable (`var`) _properties_. In the more general context of a _scope_, (e.g. a global or function local scope), we sometimes refer to these simply as a constant (`let`) or variable (`var`) rather than properties ("global property" somewhat confusing). A function has a number of _arguments_. A function has a number of named, typed values that we refer to as _parameters_, and when we call such a function, we supply _arguments_ which bind to the parameters. In `<=` above, `lhs`/`rhs` are param. (... hand side).

Comment: lhs = left hand side, meaning the value on the left of the operator, rhs = right hand side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite clear what your question is, but I'll try to answer.

`var` as you expect is short for "variable" (something that changes). This is the same keyword used in JavaScript and some other languages, so it is familiar to many programmers with an imperative background (which is most programmers).

`let` is just the word "let" and is very commonly used in math. "Let *h* be height of the triangle." In math, these things never change (even though they are technically called "variables" in math). This is a keyword used in ML and Haskell to mean "the name of something (immutable)," and is familiar to programmers with a functional background.

`lhs` is "left hand side" and `rhs` is "right hand side." They refer to the value on the left or right of an infix operator. "Infix" means "between the values," as opposed to "prefix" (before the value) and "postfix" (after the value).

Comment: Thanks, it is clear, "lhs is "left hand side" and rhs is "right hand side."". It is what I've asked.